# How to make it so that "try again" button pops up when I select the wrong answer

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
const startwords = document.getElementById('startmsg')
const endbutton = document.getElementById('end-btn')
const trybutton = document.getElementById('try-btn')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})
endbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.close()
})

function showwords (startwords) {
  questionElement.innerText = startwords.startwords

}
function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  startwords.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.slice()
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    endbutton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 4+2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '1', correct: false },
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '3', correct: false },
      { text: '6', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is 4 * 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '6', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: true }
    ]
  }
]
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: cursive,
    'Times New Roman', Times, serif
  }
  
  #particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* background-color: #b61924; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  :root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
    --hue-wrong: 0;
    --hue-correct: 145;
  }

  body {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);
  }

  body.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
  }
  
  body.wrong {
    --hue: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  
  .btn {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
    color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
  }
  
  .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .start-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .end-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .try-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .container1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: xx-large;
    padding: 40px 40px;

  }
  
  .controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="startmsgcontainer" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="startmsg">Adventure Into The Human Immune System</div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start!</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
      <button id="end-btn" class="end-btn btn hide">End (this will close the current tab)</button>
      <button id="try-btn" class="try-btn btn hide">Try again!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="uni.png" alt="image">
  </div>
 </div> 
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now the javascript just displays the "next" button regardless of whether my selected answer is right or wrong, but I want it so that the "try again" button and the current question resets when I select a wrong answer so I can try to select the right answer next time. "trybutton" is what I named my "try again" button and i tinkered around with it, but currently, the next button shows up after every question and the "try again" button is no where in sight. "particles.js" is just a background animation so I didn't include that js file.

The problem is definitely in this section in the if statements:

```
function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    endbutton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that I need to create another function to store whether the answer was correct or not and then use that function in the if statement?

Comment: Because you have a good bit of functions in your JS, I suggest placing a working snipit of your code, highlight the target function that handles where your conditional should go to evaluate users input for right and wrong answers, you will likely get a quicker response.

Comment: @dalelandry is the newly edited one good enough? I don't know what to cut and what to keep since I don't know which function is causing the problems...

Comment: in your `selectAnswer` function, there is no defined variable `answer` from?

Comment: Yeah.. your example is lacking stuff... where is the `answer` variable? Is it global? Please, try to give us a more complete example. Even with HTML, so we can play around easier.

Comment: I would add your HTML as well within a snipit. In your editor the farthest button on the right before you get to the text editing buttons will add a snipit to your answer. There you can add the relevant JavaScript, HTML and CSS to your answer and it will parse that code when the users hit `run` and allow others to see how your code is working.

Comment: @dalelandry Thanks! didn't know you could run snippets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional condition to decide which button to show next or try again after answer select and also an event listener for trybutton to reset the question
also for improvement after choosing an answer you may disable all answer buttons so it's impossible to click an answer a second time

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
const startwords = document.getElementById('startmsg')
const endbutton = document.getElementById('end-btn')
const trybutton = document.getElementById('try-btn')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})
endbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.close()
})

trybutton.addEventListener('click', setNextQuestion)

function showwords (startwords) {
  questionElement.innerText = startwords.startwords

}
function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  startwords.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.slice()
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if(correct){
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
      trybutton.classList.add('hide')
      nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
      endbutton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
  } else{
     trybutton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 4+2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '1', correct: false },
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '3', correct: false },
      { text: '6', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is 4 * 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '6', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: true }
    ]
  }
]
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: cursive,
    'Times New Roman', Times, serif
  }
  
  #particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* background-color: #b61924; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  :root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
    --hue-wrong: 0;
    --hue-correct: 145;
  }

  body {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);
  }

  body.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
  }
  
  body.wrong {
    --hue: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  
  .btn {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
    color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
  }
  
  .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .start-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .end-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .try-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .container1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: xx-large;
    padding: 40px 40px;

  }
  
  .controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="startmsgcontainer" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="startmsg">Adventure Into The Human Immune System</div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start!</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
      <button id="end-btn" class="end-btn btn hide">End (this will close the current tab)</button>
      <button id="try-btn" class="try-btn btn hide">Try again!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="uni.png" alt="image">
  </div>
 </div> 
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit: I've made an edit so try again button will be hidden after choosing right answer